# Erro: "Psi and index do not match" Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

As vezes ao clonar uma nova *branch* do projeto ou baixar um novo código ele *builda* com sucesso porém não reconhece a maioria das funções do próprio android no app.
No `log` do erro aparece "Psi and index do not match"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este erro já aconteceu mais de uma vez comigo e a solução que melhor se aplicou foi limpar o cache e reiniciar o Android Studio.

> File > Invalidate caches and restart

ATENÇÃO: Isso vai limpar todas as informações em cache.